# SRC Iframe on seperate pages Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have my markup something like this

```
<div class="images">

<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://mindlever.com.sg/economicstuition /wp-content/uploads/Why-Do-Countries-enact-Protectionism.jpg" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="Why-Do-Countries-enact-Protectionism" data-videolink="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rylkrzn7A9g">
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rylkrzn7A9g" width="460" frameborder="no" height="315"></iframe>
</a>

</div>
```

Query 1 : My jquery for getting the src (Not working):

```
  $(function(){

    var title = $(".woocommerce-main-image.zoom").attr('title');
    var src = $(".woocommerce-main-image.zoom").find('iframe').attr('src');
    alert(src);
 });
```

The result is `UNDEFINED`

Query 2 (Overall task) : To replace the href of parent anchor of iframe with its SRC value.

Reason for doing : I have video products on site. Each single video product has its own iframe loaded.The video plays in modern browsers but not in IE 9 and below. Probably because Attr `data-videolink` is not working in IE and less. Even if I can manage to change the HREF of anchor here - .jpg link here , my problem is solved. Though the video after clicking this appears on the full page instead in the iframe(thumbnail size) but can't think of any other solution right now.

Please guide me through the correct way of doing this !

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
".woocommerce-main-image zoom"
                        ^
```

You put a descendant combinator instead of the `.` for a class selector.

Comment: I corrected this and checked earlier. This is not an issue. I have edited here

Comment: This is very strange ! It still gives me UNDEFINED. I tried attaching this code to a new js file but can't get the same results.